# Creating own altcoin, error loading block database - Have Merkel and Genesis hash

Tags: bitcoind, compiling

I am creating my own altcoin on windows.  I've compiled everything, done the first build, found the hash and nonce of the genesis block as well as the merkel root, inserted them into the code, and recompiled.  When I try to run mycoind.exe, the command prompt says "Error loading block database.  Do you want to rebuild the block database now?"

I think it may be because I may have not mined the genesis block, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone out on the forums know what is causing this problem?  I will provide the code to anyone who can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: have you responded yes to rebuild the block database?  does it simply do the same thing again?  If you have included the --reindex function that may be the functionality you need.

Comment: Reindex does not work, and I cannot respond yes because the cmd just goes to another line with C:\Documents etc.